# kohana form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, input, kohana

There is a '`main.php`' view that contains a form with `email` and `name` fields and a submit button. Eveyrthing works fine with `action_index` (the code is below), but I'm curious how to modify the code below so it validates if the email was entered correctly. It should not put values in the database if the email field is not valid. I hope it is possible to made using `->rule`. Is it? If yes, then how where to add the validation? (I had no luck trying it in different ways).

```
public function action_index()
{
        if ( !empty($_POST) ) {
           $model = ORM::factory('tbl1'); // create
           $model->values($_POST); // load values to model

           if ($model->check()) {
               $model->save(); // save the model
           } else {
             //show errors
           }
        }

        $this->response->body(View::factory('main'));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read these guides? http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/security/validation and http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/validation

Comment: Yes, I've read it. Anyway, my problem is not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rules` function in your ORM model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        'email' => array(
            array('email', array(':value')),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I put it into class Model_Tbl1 extends ORM {} and used  if ( $model->rules()) in the controller instead of if ( !empty($_POST) ) and moved "$model = ORM::factory('tbl1');" before if, but it says "ORM_Validation_Exception [ 0 ]: Failed to validate array". What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Nothing, you just need to catch the exception in a try catch block and show error to the user :)